# Mails sent via smtp are not showing in the sent folder of the mail server

Tags: php, laravel

I am developing a web app using Laravel. My problem is that when the app sends any emails via smtp these emails are not showing in the sent folder of the mail server . is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you receive mail from the server?

Comment: @udipta any error occurs while sending mail?  You have set a laravel on localhost or live server?

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya mails are sending successfully . Now i want a record of sending mails on the mail server . It it possible ?

Comment: @udipta So your concern is sent mail not display on your mail server? right.

Comment: @udipta Which mail service do you use? is it a Gmail, Yahoo, Microsoft or else.

Comment: Sending mail and "storing it in Sent-folder" are two processes.
Look for imap_apend() 
https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.imap-append.php

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya ia msending mails via smtp . i am not using any mail client like gmail instead using address given by the hosting platform like abc@mywebsite.com

Answer (score 0):

Your mail provider has the choice of multiple ways to provide you access to email. Two of the more common ones are pop3 and imap. It sounds to me like you have pop3, which just pushes emails to the client and forgets about them.

You could have folders for your email, including sent messages, if your provider provides you with an imap server. Otherwise, your option is to change mail providers.

Comment: i sending via smtp

Comment: You may need to change setting for mail sending protocol out of the provider. Or you may need to enable/activate POP3 protocol.